# Is it possible to load image, scale it in memory and assign it as uri for background-image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a rollover image that makes use of a large background image that keep changing it's background-position based on which area the mouse is over.

```
$(this).mouseover(function() {
    $('#' + id).css('background-position','0 -' + thisoffset + 'px');
})
```

The problem is that I am trying to make the image scalable. With normal `<img>` tags, I could just specify width/height and it will scale, but there is no such property for background-image, so what solution do you use?

CSS3 has a background-size property, but not all web users have a CSS3 compliant browser...

=======================

Clunky, but I got it to work with GGG's answer using this layout

```
<div id="outer"
     style="width:300px;height:330px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
<img id="image"
     src="url.gif"
     style="width:100%;height:auto;position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0;z-order:-99;" />
<img id="areamap"
     src="transparent.gif"
     style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;"
     usemap="#map" />
```

This way, I only need to specify the container width once (div). The image scales to the width (100%) and the height auto-calculates using the same scale. The transparent image which is mapped fills the container entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question, it's the CSS `background-size` property. You could also use `transform`. All of this stuff is CSS3, there was no way to do it prior to that.

What you can do is use a normal `img`, scaled, and change its position within a `div` that clips it.

The HTML will look something like this:

```
<div class="map-outer"><img src="map-sprite.png"></div>
```

The CSS will look something like this:

```
.map-outer { height: 500px; width: 500px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
.map-outer img { height: 5500px; width: 500px; position: absolute; }
```

Now you can set the `top` and `left` CSS properties on the `img` in the same way that you were setting the `background-position` property before.

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi sure, if you can post the image I'll set it up. It's pretty much analagous to what you're doing, except instead of changing the background position, you change the image position.

Comment: please see comment under lukas's answer

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi you realize that if you scale this you'll have to redo the image `map` as well, right?

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi alright, I'm not sure I really feel like trying to replicate all this stuff in a fiddle (it's really late here), but I'll update my answer with the basics of how it can be done.

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi, updated... let me know if you want me to clarify or add anything.

Comment: Scaling image map is easy. I've used jQuery before, however do not remember the project for that. You can simply take the scale ratio and  multiply/divide by that ratio all the coordinates of image map. If you need it I can search for it

Answer (score 0):

You can you css3 `background-size` property for this & for IE you can use IE filter.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
      src='images/transparent-border.png',
      sizingMethod='scale');
```

Check this http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/filter

Answer (score 0):

You could trying to use `clip` CSS property on an image, to display only the rectangle you're interested; or wrap it in a DIV with `overflow : hidden`.

But it's not exactly the same of browsers that are CSS3 compliant.